# How to post a paragraph in HTML with CSS styling applied?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following code to print a paragraph when the button is clicked:

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
     const p = document.createElement('p');
     p.id    = "text";
    
    const val = document.getElementById('forminput').value;
    if (val.length) {
      p.innerHTML = val;
      document.querySelector('div').appendChild(p);
    }
});
```

When the paragraph is posted, I want it to retain the same CSS styling as well as the same onclick function as the

styling and function I use for other content.

What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: which css ? there is none in your question ...

Comment: What does same styling means?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some styling set up for your p tags already, then this would automatically apply when you render the new p tag.

Else you can create a custom css class that holds the styling you're wanting to apply, and then add this classList to your newly rendered p tag as follows:

```
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.classList.add('your-class');
```

Comment: This works great to get the styling! Thank you!

PS - is there any way to make the onclick function work too?